# Using Move-Item -Destination to move files to a new share

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that prompts the user to answer a series of questions.  Once those questions are answered, the script determines (based on the answer provided) what files need to be moved from the source path to the destination path.

Everything worked fine with the script until I modified it to include user input for the destination path (before this I put the path in the script) as you will see in the `$endpath` variable.

When I run the script, it looks as if it is running fine, completes, but it didn't move the files.

```
$earliesttime = "00/00/0000"
$lasttime = "00/00/0000"
$size2 = 0
$user = ""
$sourcepath = $null
$endpath = $null
while ($sourcepath -eq $null) {
    $sourcepath = Read-Host "Enter source file path"
}
Set-Location $sourcepath
while ($endpath -eq $null) {
    $endpath = Read-Host "Enter destination file path"
}
Set-Location $endpath
Write-Host
switch ($what = Read-Host "Do you want to search by owner?") {
    No {
        while ($earliesttime -eq "00/00/0000") {
            Write-Host
            $earliesttime = Read-Host "What is the earliest date of modification?"
        }
        while ($lasttime -eq "00/00/0000") {
            Write-Host
            $lasttime = Read-Host "What is the latest date of modification?"
        }
        Write-Host
        $skip1 = Read-Host "Do you want to search by size?"
        if ($skip1 -match "yes") {
            while ($size2 -eq 0) {
                $size2 = Read-Host "What is the size in KB of the objects you are looking for?"
            }
            if ($size2 -ge 1) {
                Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {
                    $_.Length /1KB -ge $size2 -and
                    $_.LastWriteTime -ge $earliesttime -and
                    $_.LastWriteTime -le $lasttime
                } | Move-Item -Destination "$endpath"
            }
        } elseif ($skip1-match "no") {
            Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {
                $_.LastWriteTime -ge $earliesttime -and
                $_.LastWriteTime -le $lasttime
            } | Move-Item -Destination "$endpath"
        }
    }
    Yes {
        while ($user -eq "") {
            Write-Host
            $user = Read-Host "What is the name of the owner (i.e. john.smith)?"
        }
        while ($earliesttime -eq "00/00/0000") {
            Write-Host
            $earliesttime = Read-Host "What is the earliest date of modification?"
        }
        while ($lasttime -eq "00/00/0000") {
            Write-Host
            $lasttime = Read-Host "What is the latest date of modification?"
        }
        Write-Host
        $skip1 = Read-Host "Do you want to search by size?"
        if ($skip1 -match "yes") {
            while ($size2 -eq 0) {
                $size2 = Read-Host " What is the size in KB of the objects you are looking for?"
            }
            if ($size2 -ge 1) {
                Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {
                    $_.GetAccessControl().Owner -eq $user -and
                    $_.Length /1KB -ge $size2 -and
                    $_.LastWriteTime -ge $earliesttime -and
                    $_.LastWriteTime -le $lasttime
                } | Move-Item -Destination "$endpath"
            }
        } elseif ($skip1 -match "no") {
            Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {
                $_.GetAccessControl().Owner -eq $user -and
                $_.LastWriteTime -ge $earliesttime -and
                $_.LastWriteTime -le $lasttime
            } | Move-Item -Destination "$endpath"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue here:

```
while ($sourcepath -eq $null) {
    $sourcepath = Read-Host "Enter source file path"
}
Set-Location $sourcepath
while ($endpath -eq $null) {
    $endpath = Read-Host "Enter destination file path"
}
Set-Location $endpath
```

So you're setting your $SourcePath as your current location, but then right after that, you're setting your current location as your $EndPath.

Set-Location is the equivalent of `cd` so you are basically changing directories last minute to the directory you wanted to copy files to. Then you are trying to copy files from that location to itself.

You would want to remove the `Set-Location $endpath` line or change your Get-ChildItems to `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourcepath -Recurse | ...`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I actually wondered about that myself.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello Shawn, how do I do that?